# Gridview Data Bind Error

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I cannot get the GridView to bind to DataRowView with the datasource below, however it does work if I use the wildcard.?

THIS FAILS:
ERROR: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum'

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" 
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" PageSize="100">
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="75" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" HeaderText="AutoNum" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitTime" HeaderText="SubmitTime" SortExpression="SubmitTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassName" HeaderText="ClassName" SortExpression="ClassName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassDate" HeaderText="ClassDate" SortExpression="ClassDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCompleted" HeaderText="DateCompleted" SortExpression="DateCompleted" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False"/>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Completed" HeaderText="Completed" SortExpression="Completed" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EnrollmentsTbl.UID" HeaderText="UID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EnrollmentsTbl.UID" />
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#6699CC" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [EnrollmentsTbl] WHERE [EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum] = ?" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum, EnrollmentsTbl.SubmitTime, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassName, 
    EnrollmentsTbl.ClassDate, EnrollmentsTbl.DateCompleted, EnrollmentsTbl.Completed, EnrollmentsTbl.UID  
    FROM [EnrollmentsTbl] INNER JOIN [UsersDataTbl] ON EnrollmentsTbl.UID = UsersDataTbl.UID 
    WHERE ([EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum] > ?)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [EnrollmentsTbl] SET [UserName] = ?, [SubmitTime] = ?, [ClassName] = ?, [ClassDate] = ?, 
    [ClassTime] = ?, [Enrolled] = ?, [WaitListed] = ?, [Instructor] = ?, [DateCompleted] = ?, [Completed] = ?, [Walkin] = ? 
    WHERE [EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum] = ?">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UserNameTB" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SubmitTime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassTime" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Enrolled" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="WaitListed" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Instructor" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DateCompleted" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Completed" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Walkin" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

However:
changing the `SELECTCOMMAND="SELECT * FROM...` allows it to work?

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [EnrollmentsTbl] WHERE [EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum] = ?" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT *  
    FROM [EnrollmentsTbl] INNER JOIN [UsersDataTbl] ON EnrollmentsTbl.UID = UsersDataTbl.UID 
    WHERE ([EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum] > ?)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [EnrollmentsTbl] SET [UserName] = ?, [SubmitTime] = ?, [ClassName] = ?, [ClassDate] = ?, 
    [ClassTime] = ?, [Enrolled] = ?, [WaitListed] = ?, [Instructor] = ?, [DateCompleted] = ?, [Completed] = ?, [Walkin] = ? 
    WHERE [EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum] = ?">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UserNameTB" DefaultValue="" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SubmitTime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClassTime" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Enrolled" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="WaitListed" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Instructor" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DateCompleted" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Completed" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Walkin" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I need fields from bith tabes in the gridview so the wildcard is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

No help offered, but it appears I found a resolution/work-a-round:

Part of the problem was that when the wildcard (*) is used in the SELECT statement `(SelectCommand)` the fields returned from an `INNER JOIN` are mixed, some have table.column and others just column. example: if both tables contain `AutoNum` then table1.AutoNum and table2.AutNum are both returned - but if only one table has a field it is returned as only `Field` - this was the problem with setting the column names in the gridview that was causing my problem.